# How do you check if a number is in a list with Java (no given parameters)

Tags: java

```
public int FirstNineIndexFromStart() {
    if (first != null) {
        if(this.first.item == 9.0)
            return 0;
        int index = 0;
        for (Node i = this.first; i != null; i = i.next) {
            if (i.item == 9.0)
                return index;
            index+=1;
        }
        return index;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The goal of the project is to check the first index that the number 9 is at in a list from the start.

The two conditionals that must be met are that, if a list begins with the number 9, return the position number 0. If the list does not contain a 9 at all, return a -1.

Everything runs fine - EXCEPT if a 9 is not in the list. My test code gives me the wrong answer. It is not spitting out a -1 to be accounted for. Can someone please tell me how to make sure that, if a 9 is not present, it returns a -1?

I cannot use functions for this either. So, I cannot use `contains()`.

Comment: Just don't return `index` after the loop. If you find the result you''ll return from inside the loop anyway.

Comment: ***if(this.first.item == 9.0)*** never ever!!!

Comment: I'm sort of confused what you mean. Can you clarify? I'm confused what to return or not to

Comment: @geltatin4902 If you're referring to my comment, see shmosel's response below. It's basically the same thing I said but a bit more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the loop completes, the number was not found. Change the second `return index;` to `return -1;`.

Note that there's no need for a special case for the first item. The loop should do the job just fine.

Comment: Something is now not working for me. I'm getting errors with my brackets if the last line is return -1;